# On a RAID controller card, what is the difference between the connector, port, and device numbers?

Tags: raid, port, sas, sata, connector

I'm looking at RAID controllers, specifically the (Avago) LSI Logic MegaRAID SAS 9261-8i.  It is a 8-port card, which I would be able to "Connect up to 128 SATA or SAS drives with eight internal 6 Gb/s SATA and SAS ports" but I only see two connectors.

Can someone please explain how the connectors/ports/devices relate? Thanks!